# Problemas a la hora de hacer consultas a una BBDD en servidor MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando un programa que recoja datos de una BBDD de un servidor. Antes tenía la conexión en un archivo "conexion.php" y lo incluía con un require/require_once (no sé cuál es más óptimo) pero lo he metido el código en el mismo archivo para que no haya problemas a la hora de hacer la conexión. El caso es que estoy intentando hacer una consulta simple de prueba, pero no sé cómo mostrarla en pantalla ni si la estoy haciendo bien, revisando la variable dónde almaceno los resultados de la consulta con el método var_dump() me sale directamente null. Este es el código:

```
$conWebService=new mysqli("servername", "username", "password", database);
$resultWebService="";

if($conWebService){
    $resultWebService= "connected";
} else {
    $resultWebService= "problemas en la conexión";
}

echo $resultWebService;
      echo "<br>";
      $query="SELECT DNI FROM pedidos WHERE IdPedido='346212-A'";
      $prueba=mysqli_query($conWebService, $query);
      $dnis=mysqli_fetch_assoc($prueba);

      var_dump($dnis);
```

$dnis me da null y no tengo ni idea de dónde estoy fallando ni de cómo mostrar los resultados de forma adecuada. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué imprime esto: `echo $resultWebService;`? Si imprime `connected`, quizá hay un error de sintaxis en la consulta, haz esta prueba rápida: **`var_dump(mysqli_error($conWebService));`** (colócalo al final del todo) y dinos qué muestra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente

```
$conWebService=new mysqli("servername", "username", "password", "database);
$resultWebService="";

 if($conWebService){
    $resultWebService= "connected";
 } else {
    $resultWebService= "problemas en la conexión";
 }

//imprimes el estado de la conexion
  echo $resultWebService;
```

Ahora creamos el query y lo enviamos para su ejecución

```
$query="SELECT DNI FROM pedidos WHERE IdPedido='346212-A'";

$result = $conWebService->query($query);
$resultArray  = array();
//recorremos los registros y los almacenamos en $resulArray
    foreach( $result  as $registros ){
        $resultArray[] = $registros;
    }

print_r($resultArray);
```